# Why we need secant equation to approximate Hessian matrix in Quasi-Newton method?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

As mentioned in [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method#Search_for_extrema:_optimization), after approximating function value with Taylor expansion to the 2nd order, we have the secant equation $\nabla f(\vec{x_k}+\Delta \vec{x})=\nabla f(\vec{x_k})+B\Delta \vec{x}$ to solve for the approximated matrix of Hessian, $B$.

My question is why don't we directly use the Hessian of $f(\vec{x_k})$?

Comment: To save the expense of computing it, essentially.

Comment: Cool. I was wondering since methods, like BFGS update $B_k$ with a rank 2 updates (as in [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm#Rationale)). Would there be some reason related to enforce the positive definiteness of $B_k$ when updating?